# Java problems faced while doing the read/delete from txt file

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a delete function with Java, by using the code below.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcMg.png) is my original txt file, and I wish to delete one line inside that file, so that I get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNWYT.png). With my code, however, I get: `1, 1234, javago`

Can anyone help me to sort this out? How could I get my desired output?

```
public class delete {
    
    private static Scanner x;   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String filepath = "easy.txt";
        String removeLine = "3333";     
        removeRecord(filepath,removeLine);      
    }
    
    public static void removeRecord(String filepath, String removeLine) {
        
        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String no = ""; String ISBN = ""; String title = "";
        
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            
            while (x.hasNext()) {
                no = x.next();
                ISBN = x.next();
                title = x.next();
                
                if (!ISBN.equals(removeLine)) {
                    pw.println(no + "," + ISBN + ","   + title );
                }
                
                x.close();
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                oldFile.delete();
                File dump = new File(filepath);
                newFile.renameTo(dump);             
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error !!!");
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63817656/13864358 gives you your expected output

Comment: As soon as you close the Scanner with x.close(), it's not going to scan anything else.  You want to move that line and the following lines - to the "newFile.renameTo(dump) line - outside the while loop so those only run after the entire file has been scanned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are closing the scanner and other writers in the `while` scope. Probably you placed the closing bracket in the wrong line.

There is nothing wrong in using `.equals` to compare strings. You could also use `Objects.equals` as this would give you an advantage over the `null` in your values.

You should change your code as follows:

```
public static void RemoveRecord(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, String removeLine) {
    File oldFile = new File(inputFilePath);
    File newFile = new File(outputFilePath);
    
    String no = ""; String ISBN = ""; String title = "";
    
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        
        while (x.hasNext())
        {
            no = x.next();
            ISBN = x.next();
            title = x.next();
            
            // Using Objects.equals is better here
            if (!Objects.equals(ISBN , removeLine + ','))
            {
                pw.println(no + "," + ISBN + ","   + title );
            }
        }
        
        // This code should be placed outside the while loop
        x.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        oldFile.delete();

        File dump = new File(filepath);
        newFile.renameTo(dump);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error !!!");
    }           
}
```

Please give this a try and let me know if there are any problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors.

1. Please read the comment.

   ```
   no = x.next(); // no = "1,"
   ISBN = x.next(); // ISBN = "1234,"
   title = x.next(); // title = javago

   if (!ISBN.equals(removeLine))
   {
       // No need to add comma here, it is already in a string.
       // That's why you have double comma like "1,," "
       // Change "," to " " (space) instead.
       pw.println(no + "," + ISBN + ","   + title );
   }
   ```
2. Since `ISBN` includes comma, obviously it won't be equal to `"3333"` (without comma).
3. You are closing all the objects (Scanner, etc) inside a loop. Please put them outside a while loop.

Comment: I read the comments and done modification, the old result is fixed, but I still cannot get the desired output

Comment: What is your current output? I suggest you editing your question and update your current status there (output + current code), so it's easier for people to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code works fine!

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "easy.txt";
        String removeLine = "3333,";
        removeRecord(filepath, removeLine);
    }

    public static void removeRecord(String filepath, String removeLine) {

        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        File oldFile = new File(filepath);
        File newFile = new File(tempFile);
        String no = "";
        String ISBN = "";
        String title = "";

        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            Scanner x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));

            while (x.hasNext()) {
                no = x.next();
                ISBN = x.next();
                title = x.next();

                if (!ISBN.equals(removeLine)) {
                    pw.println(no + " " + ISBN + " " + title);
                }
            }

            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error !!!");
        }
    }
}
```

input from file

```
1, 12312, java
2, 33213, hello
3, 3333, delete
4, 123, last
```

output written to file

```
1, 12312, java
2, 33213, hello
4, 123, last
```

Comment: I have tried but the txt file does not have any changes. Is it my own problem ?

Comment: contents gets deleted from easy.txt

Comment: I tried the whole code, but still no changes in result

Comment: whats the output exactly or nothing is happening?